# C# get file location from client-side

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, browser

I need user to select file on his computer and get only location of that file (not to upload). Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Ile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible - actually there is not solution that works in all browsers. Thanks to Marnix van Valen for answer (comments)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `javascript with ActivxObject` to get file detail of client machine

see the following article might help you 
[Using JavaScript to read a client-side file](http://timstall.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/using_javascript_to_read_a_clientside_file.htm)

Comment: how about usage of flash? is it possible to do it with usage of flash?

Comment: yes you can do it with flash but have no idea about because i am not falsh devloper

Answer (score 0):

you could create a <file ...> input and when the user clicks the submit button, read the value of the input and then remove it from the DOM before the form is submitted.

I'm not sure if there's a better way.

Comment: That won't work. The value of the file input is not accessible from javascript for security reasons.

Comment: ah, wasn't aware of that.  Thanks for the info. Is this consistent across browsers?

Comment: I need to correct my previous comment. It's not possible to SET the value of a file input. It is however possible to read the value. So you solution should work. However most browsers will however return only the file name, not the full path. I tried this in Chrome, FF and IE8. Only IE8 returns the full path.